# Getting incorrect output for 2 of my patterns

Tags: java

I can't seem to get the output right for pattern 3 or 4. Instead of replacing the @ symbol it just places the * after it. Here is my code for Patterns.java and PatternsTest.java:

Patterns:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package APatterns;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
*
* @author Jacob
*/
public class Patterns {

public static void pattern1 (int size)
{   
    InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (istream);

    System.out.print("Size: ");

    int num = 0;

    try
    {
        num=Integer.parseInt( read.readLine() );
    } 

    catch(IOException | NumberFormatException Number)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Number!");
    }

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < num - (i-1); j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
                {
                    System.out.print("@");

                    for(int k1 = 1; k1 < k; k1 += k)
                    {
                        System.out.print("@");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
}

public static void pattern2 (int size)
{
    InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (istream);

    System.out.print("Size: ");

    int num = 0;

    try
    {
        num=Integer.parseInt( read.readLine() );
    } 

    catch(IOException | NumberFormatException Number)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Number!");
    }

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j > 1; j--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k = 1; k <= num - (i-1); k++)
            {
                System.out.print("@");

                for(int k1 = 1; k1 < k; k1 += k)
                {
                    System.out.print("@");
                }
            }
                System.out.println(); 
        }
}

public static void pattern3 (int size)
{ 
    InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (istream);

    System.out.print("Size: ");

    int num = 0;

    try
    {
        num=Integer.parseInt( read.readLine() );
    } 

    catch(IOException | NumberFormatException Number)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Number!");
    }

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < num - (i-1); j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
                {
                    System.out.print("@");

                    if (k == i / 2)
                    {
                        System.out.print ("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print ("@");
                    }

                    for(int k1 = 1; k1 < k; k1 += k)
                    {
                        System.out.print("@");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
}

public static void pattern4 (int size)
{
    InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader (istream);

    System.out.print("Size: ");

    int num = 0;

    try
    {
        num=Integer.parseInt( read.readLine() );
    } 

    catch(IOException | NumberFormatException Number)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Number!");
    }

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            for (int j=i; j > 1; j--)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k = 1; k <= num - (i-1); k++)
            {
                System.out.print("@");

                if (k == i / 2)
                    {
                        System.out.print ("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print ("@");
                    }

                for(int k1 = 1; k1 < k; k1 += k)
                {
                    System.out.print("@");
                }
            }
                System.out.println(); 
        }
    }

}
```

PatternsTest:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package APatterns;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Jacob
*/
public class PatternsTest {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int methodNumber;

    do 
    {

        System.out.print("Choose a pattern (1-4) or 0 to quit: ");
        methodNumber = input.nextInt();

        switch (methodNumber) 
        {

        case 1:
            Patterns.pattern1(methodNumber);
            break;
        case 2:
            Patterns.pattern2(methodNumber);
            break;
        case 3:
            Patterns.pattern3(methodNumber);
            break;
        case 4:
            Patterns.pattern4(methodNumber);
            break;
        }

    } while (methodNumber != 0);
}
}
```

The output for patterns 1 and 2 are correct but not 3 and 4.

Here is the output:

```
Choose a pattern (1-4) or 0 to quit: 1
Size: 5
    @
   @@@
  @@@@@
 @@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@
Choose a pattern (1-4) or 0 to quit: 2
Size: 5
@@@@@@@@@
 @@@@@@@
  @@@@@
   @@@
    @
Choose a pattern (1-4) or 0 to quit: 3
Size: 5
    @@
   @*@@@
  @*@@@@@@
 @@@*@@@@@@@
@@@*@@@@@@@@@@
Choose a pattern (1-4) or 0 to quit: 4
Size: 5
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
 @*@@@@@@@@@
  @*@@@@@@
   @@@*@
    @@
Choose a pattern (1-4) or 0 to quit: 0
```

3 and 4 should have an * down the center column like so:

```
Choose a pattern (1-4) or 0 to quit: 3
Size: 5
    *
   @*@
  @@*@@
 @@@*@@@
@@@@*@@@@
Choose a pattern (1-4) or 0 to quit: 4
Size: 5
@@@@*@@@@
 @@@*@@@
  @@*@@
   @*@
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you study [how integer division works in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2).

Comment: I understand how integer division works. My professor told me what algorithm I need to calculate the center point of the columns and print an * there. What I have for the if statement is exactly what he instructed me to put and we couldn't figure out any other way to do it other than that. He said that the center point is taken from 0-4 so 4 / 2 = 2 which is the center point.

Comment: What happens when i is odd in the following code? 

`if (k == i / 2)`

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm trying to guide you to your own solution without just fixing your code for you.